# Xterm right click misbehaviors

Tags: eclipse, xterm

When I open linux eclipse IDE from windows using xterm(Reflection, MobaXterm), I found few problems:

1. When I right-click on a project, the menu appears for a millisecond, and disappears with a click action on about.
2. Sometimes the menu appears on right click, but if that menu has more items, usually it should scroll down/up, but the scroll button staying behind windows tast bar.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue too. It seems that the right-click menu disapears behind the Eclipse main window and behind the Windows taskbar...

Here is the workaround I use currently: in [MobaXterm 5.0](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net), just go to "settings" --> "X11" and choose "Windowed mode with Fvwm": this will open an X11 window.

When you run Eclipse using this tip, it correctly displays the right-click menu.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I googled but didn't find a solution.
For the first one, you can right click and hold it, move the mouse to the target menu entry, then release it.
In this way you can avoid a wrong click.